# c# Excel relative FormulaR1C1 not working

Tags: c#, excel, formula

I have, may be a simple problem.

I want to put a relative formula with C# into an excel-worksheet. The fixed formula-format works and calculate the value correctly.

But with the relative format, Excel won’t calculate the value. If I activate the cell into the worksheet  and click into the editing bar and hit enter the value was correctly calculated.

Excel autocalculate is on and recalculate the worksheet won't work, only hit enter works?

What’s going wrong?

Thanks Steffen

```
private void SetFormula(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int Count)
{
    if (Count == 0) return;
    int column = 5;
    for (int row = 2; row <= Count + 1; row++)
    {
        //((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row, column]).FormulaR1C1 = $"=R{row}C3-R{row}C4"; // fixed Format this works
        ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row, column]).Clear();  // Feld zurücksetzen
        ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[row, column]).FormulaR1C1 = $"=RC(-2)-RC(-1)"; // relative Format, this not work
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop the $ and I would suggest putting the relative formula into all cells at once.

Comment: I have found that if you end the formula with "*1" ie multiply by 1 it can force the calculation.

Comment: You should be using `[]` in the formula, not `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rory :)

> using [] in the formula instead of () works

thanks
Steffen